# Show with siblings on springs

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I think the show was on Hulu and it had really short episodes. It was about this brother and sister (I think one was blue and one was a pinkish-red) and they didn’t talk. They physically fought all the time. They didn’t have legs, they had springs for legs. I feel like I remember there being some sort of extending punching glove in an episode. There was also an episode with a short wall. It was on at around the same time as *Robot and Monster* I think.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're thinking of ***[Angus & Cheryl](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4807870/)*** (2006).

From [Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicky_%26_Johnny):

> *Vicky & Johnny* (Korean: 비키와 조니; RR: *Bikiwa Joni*) is a South Korean-Spanish series of animated shorts produced by Tuba Entertainment in South Korea and BRB Internacional, Screen 21 and Televisió de Catalunya in Spain. While the shorts are known as *Vicky & Johnny* in South Korea and parts of Asia, they are distributed in the rest of the world as *Angus & Cheryl* by BRB Internacional.

From IMDB:

> Boys and girls just can't get along - or can they? Angus and Cheryl live in a shared house, and have quite a few problems getting along.

It's a series of 3D-animated shorts about a boy and girl who live in the same house, bounce around on springs, and seemingly can't get along. There also doesn't appear to be any dialogue in the show, just music and sound effects.

In the title, Angus' name is written in blue and Cheryl's in a dark pink or purple.